# set button disabled dynamically with attribute directive in angular

Tags: angular

I have an attribute component with adds a spinner to a button:

spinner-button.component.html:

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
   @if (showSpinner()) {
    <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm"></span>
  }
```

spinner-button.comonent.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: '[pvp-spinner-button]',
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './spinner-button.component.html',
  styleUrl: './spinner-button.component.css'
})
export class SpinnerButtonComponent {

  constructor(private service:Service,private el:ElementRef) {
    el.nativeElement.disabled = service.busy;
  }

  showSpinner(){
    return this.service.busy;
  }
}
```

But el.nativeElement.disabled is set once at component creation and does not change on changes. How can I achieve that it is dynamically set on changes.

I am using attribute binding because I want to insert the button in a bootstrap button group where there are no surrounding tags allowed.

Comment: You are only setting the disabled attribute in the constructor. You can do this in the showSpinner() method.

Comment: this works, but showSpinner() is called very often. Seems like a dirty side effekt. Is that the angular way to do it?

Comment: It is not the ideal way to do it.
I suggest reading into https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496
and https://angular.io/guide/change-detection

You could implement this by using a BehaviourSubject in the Service and subscribing to the changes in the template (using an async pipe).

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [@HostBinding (angular.io)](https://angular.io/api/core/HostBinding) and bind to `attr.disabled`. Please note that you'd have to return `null` if the button should be enabled. Because the pure presence of the disabled attribute initializes the button's attribute to true.

So in your case it would be:

```
@HostBinding('attr.disabled') get disabled() { return service.busy ? true : null }
```